# NameServer do not forward

Tags: dns, vps, plesk

i bought a domain at networksolutions and try to forward dns to my vps, the problem is, its not forward when i try to open page, ie gave me that error.

i also use the plesk panel

> > ERROR
>
> The requested URL could not be retrieved
>
> The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL:
>   http://ertugoto.com/
>
> Unable to determine IP address from host name ertugoto.com
>
> The DNS server returned:
>
> Server Failure: The name server was unable to process this query. This
>   means that the system was not able to resolve the hostname presented
>   in the URL. Check if the address is correct.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you do not have DNS name servers configured for that domain. At least the DNS roots do not know about them. You will need to work with network solutions to have them add glue records for your name servers, or if they are hosting the DNS for you then you need to add the NS records etc for your domain.